# pandas.DataFrameの結合を自動化したいです。

Tags: python, pandas

画像のように、沢山のデータフレームから任意の列を抜き出して右へと結合していき新たなデータフレームを作りたいと思いgoogle colaboratoryでコードを書いています。沢山の列を結合させようとfor文を使用してコードを書いているのですが、取り出した列を結合させる段階でエラーが起きたり、最後に取り出した列しか表示されなかったりします。検索しても同じようなエラーが起きるので詰まっております。どのように改善すれば良いのでしょうか。株価のデータで練習していたので、コードもそのまま載せております。

[image: やりたいこと]

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pandas_datareader.stooq import StooqDailyReader
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.dates as mdate

codes =[1301,1332,1333]
start = datetime(2021, 6, 1)
end = datetime(2021, 6, 22)
  
for n in codes:
    
    brand = str(n) + '.JP'
    stooq = StooqDailyReader(brand, start, end) #stooqから株価情報を取得
    data = stooq.read() 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data) #データフレーム化
    df = df.iloc[::-1]
    df = df["Close"] #終値だけ取り出す
    df = df.drop(columns ='Date') 
    df = df.rename({'Close':'brand'})
    
    print(df,type(df))
    dfc=pd.concat([dfc,df], axis=1)
```

以下、エラー内容

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-49461954e53c> in <module>()
     27 
     28     print(df,type(df))
---> 29     dfc=pd.concat([dfc,df], axis=1)
     30 
     31 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    357                     "only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"
    358                 )
--> 359                 raise TypeError(msg)
    360 
    361             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下では list comprehension(リスト内包表記)で `dfc` を作成しています。

※ 元のコードでは日付(index)を削除して銘柄コードを全て `brand` という文字列に置き換えてしまっていますが、少し判りづらい様に見えます。

```py
dfc = pd.concat([
          StooqDailyReader(f'{n}.JP', start, end).read()
          .iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True).Close
          .rename('brand')
        for n in codes
      ], axis=1)

print(dfc)

# 結果
    brand  brand  brand
0    2974    514   2435
1    2918    516   2435
2    2936    534   2465
3    2935    540   2455
4    2942    548   2448
5    2924    561   2494
6    2950    560   2513
7    2947    547   2477
8    2924    543   2431
9    2931    542   2425
10   2949    546   2457
11   2940    546   2431
12   2934    543   2419
13   2915    535   2391
14   2900    521   2328
15   2901    539   2427
```

##### 追記

[pandas_datareader.stooq.StooqDailyReader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readers/stooq.html#module-pandas_datareader.stooq) の場合、複数の銘柄をリストにして指定できますので、以下の様に書く事もできます。

```py
dfc = (
       StooqDailyReader([f'{n}.JP' for n in codes], start, end).read()
       .Close.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
       .set_axis(['brand']*len(codes), axis=1)
     )
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。見事に解決しました！次はご指摘の分かりづらくなっている点を改善していきます。ありがとうございました。